# How can I specify a custom linker configuration for Xamarin.iOS when building from Visual Studio 2015?

Tags: xamarin, visual-studio-2015, xamarin.ios

I am building my Xamarin.iOS app from Visual Studio against my Mac build host and use PostSharp to perform AOP against the output, before the binaries are sent to my Mac build host for AOT/native compilation.

PostSharp injects some hidden implementation types into the target assembly which are not referenced by my application so the AOT compiler strips them from the resulting binary, because I am using the "Link All" option.

Changing the "Link All" option to "Link SDK" or "None" fixes the issue but produces a very large binary so it cannot be used for releasing the app.

Since the code is generated by a tool, I cannot use the [Preserve] attribute on the code directly, and because it is internal / private I cannot manually reference it in my application code.

According to the following documentation I can specify a linker xml file to specify the type names by hand:

https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/advanced/custom_linking/

I have successfully used this technique for my Xamarin.Android app, and I can also successfully use this technique when compiling my Xamarin.iOS app in Xamarin Studio on a Mac.

However I cannot figure out how to accomplish this when compiling the Xamarin.iOS app from Visual Studio 2015. Although I can add the necessary mtouch arguments in the .csproj file, I cannot figure out how to deliver the xml file to the Mac build host during the build process.

Comment: Is the linker XML being copied to the build host? You should see it in the build output.

One thing to check is that the file is referenced in the project with the correct type. I had an issue with un-referenced assets not being copied over to the mac build host. 

They worked fine from Xamarin Studio because they didn't need to be referenced to work but using Visual Studio with a remote host they were missing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure the linker XML file is included in your project file and the output type is set to `Copy Always`.

The Visual Studio build copies the output directory to the build host and it won't copy your linker XML file over unless the project configuration is correct.